# Dual monitors say "no signal" but windows boots completely

Tags: boot, display, graphics-card, motherboard

I turned my PC on today and the monitors said "no signal" and entered power saver mode. After restarting a few times I tried to see if the PC booted up by typing my password in and seeing if Spotify on my phone would show my PC pop up under devices, it does and I can control music on my phone to play through my PC but the monitors stay blank so I assume windows fully boots? The VGA light on my motherboard is lit up a solid white. I've had my GPU for a year and upgraded my CPU and motherboard a month ago.

I've tried swapping my display port from my GPU to my motherboard, unplugging everything and powering on, removing and reinserting GPU, different display port cables, cleared CMOS by removing battery and my monitors are still saying no signal. I'm not sure if the CMOS cleared since the monitors are still blank. I haven't had any issues with graphics or anything like this so far.

- ASUS ROG Strix B760-A Gaming WiFi 6E ATX
- Intel Core i7-12700KF
- Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro SL 16GB
- ZOTAC Gaming GeForce RTX 3060 Twin Edge OC 12GB GDDR6

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically the "F" processor line on intel shouldn't come with integrated graphics, but just in case I'd give it a shot to boot without the GPU for one to see if it at least shows you the BIOS (assuming it's not even displaying that).

To clear a doubt for you, taking out the battery should definitely clear CMOS, at the very least it will reset the RTC aka, your PC's clock. Mind that it won't reset BIOS settings though, nowadays BIOSes store those somewhere else, not in the CMOS.

Lastly, if you have access to either, another PC or another GPU I'd try discarding options, as in, try booting another PC with your GPU and see if it gives image, likewise, try another GPU in your PC just in case.

Things to keep in mind:

- Be fully sure that the RAM is properly seated and locked in place
- If it's a dual-ram setup, remember that (unless your motherboard has literally only 2 slots) they should be 1 slot apart from each (like 1 & 3 or 2 & 4)
- Make sure every component is in it's right place and no loose parts are roaming around.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As per [this entry on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUSROG/comments/1846c9o/rog_strix_b760a_gaming_wifi_d4_bios_update_need/), what you described can happen after BIOS update.

Follow the instruction manual for you MB on what to do in case of a BIOS update that failed, alternatively try to do what OP on Reddit did, in one of the comments:

> What happened is the VGA Led solid white is the reason that's why
> there's no display, but the BIOS update was finished even though
> there's no display. I just hit "F1" in black screen and then proceed
> to the BIOS set up and the BIOS is up to date.